# referencing a function's arguments by position?

Tags: c++

I'm not sure I know how to ask this.

say I have a function

```
void myFunc ( int8 foo, float bar, int whatever )
{
...
}
```

is there a quick way of referencing a particular argument by its position?

```
void myFunc ( float foo, float bar, float whatever )
{
   float f;
   f = ARG[1]; // f now equals bar
}
```

something to that effect?

Follow up:

Thank you for your answers folks. I guess I'm going about it wrong. I find it odd that c++ doesn't allow for this, as perl and some psuedo languages (I'm thinking in particular of AutoIt) do.  So as for "why"?  Just to use a simple loop to go through them.  I recognize that there are a myriad of better ways to achieve this in normal circumstances, but I was trying my darndest to not modify anyone's code outside of my little world. In other words I don't have control over the calling code. It is shoving the inputs down my throat and I have to manage them as best as possible.  So I can't just loop before calling my function.  Anyway, it was clearly going to be a mess and there weren't that many variables so I just duplicated code.  No biggy.  Thanks for the comments and interesting suggestions.

Comment: `new` is not a valid variable name, by the way.

Comment: There isn't, because in general there is no good reason to do that. If you were to explain why you think you need to, we could suggest alternatives.

Comment: why not just float temp = bar;?

Comment: please clarify if all your parameters have the same type or not

Comment: @moonshadow, surely there is. Check my answer.

Comment: @Kirill: There isn't a way to do what he wants.  There are ways to do similar things, such as pass arbitrary numbers of values, and those are the alternatives.  Your tuple suggestion is one, as is passing a vector or using a variadic function.

Comment: @David, variadic function has no compile time type checking. vector is limited to only one type at once. I believe that tuple is best what you can get with standard C++.

Comment: It's not the same, is the point. It's emulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it really seems like what you need is a parameter array of values of the same type instead of explicitly named parameters, then you can just pass an array as a parameter.

```
void myFunc ( float foo[3] )
{
    float bar;
    bar = foo[1];
}
```

That can be inefficient if your array is much longer, so a better solution would be using a const reference like this:

```
void myFunc ( const float & foo[3] )
{
    float bar;
    bar = foo[1];
}
```

Or like so many c++ questions on this site, the best solution is to use a std::vector

```
void myFunc ( const std::vector<float> & foo )
{
    float bar;
    bar = foo[1];
}
```

Answer (score 8):

May be [boost::tuple](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html) is what you need?

```
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>

void myFunc ( const boost::tuple<int, float, double>& t )
{
   float f;
   f = boost::get<1>(t); // f now equals bar
}

int main()
{
    myFunc( boost::make_tuple( 1, 2.0f, 3.0 ) );
}
```

It gives you static type checking and you could get elements by its position. Tuples are part of future standard. It could be used as `std::tr1::tuple` already with some compilers.

If all arguments are the same type you could use `std::vector`:

```
#include <vector>

void myFunc ( const std::vector<float>& t )
{
   float f;
   f = t[1]; // f now equals bar
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<float> f_array;
    f_array.push_back( 1.0f );
    f_array.push_back( 2.0f );
    f_array.push_back( 3.0f );
    myFunc( f_array );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not in C or C++, no.

As moonshadow suggests: what actual problem are you trying to solve?

(If you want to add an explanation, please edit your question rather than leaving a comment on this answer - more people will see your edit that way.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use C-style variable arguments:

```
#include <stdarg.h>

void myFunc (int8 foo, ...)
{
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, foo);

  float bar = va_arg(args, float);
  int whatever = va_arg(args, int);

  va_end(args);
}
```

but this means that:

1. You need to know, in advance, the
   parameters that will be used to call
   the function.
2. You do not get any
   benefits of static type checking.

Comment: In C++, there is almost no reason at all to do this. If you do it anyway, you lose all static checking of function parameters. Now what's the value in this?

Answer (score 1):

No there is not a standards compliant way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`<cstdarg>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdarg/) header.

Just remember that you will not get indexed access to the arguments, but you can write a loop and call [`va_arg`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdarg/va_list/) till you reach the argument you want. Figuring out the argument's data type will be your next problem.